# A list of different types of dependency injections patterns/methods?

Tags: dependency-injection

I'm trying to make a list of the different types of dependency injection methods.

Been reading quite a few blogs and everyone takes up different things.

The list I've come up with so far as follows:

- Pure DI/Poor mans DI
- Explicit register (DI container)
- Convention over configuration

Also the related types of the actual injections:

- Constructor injection (most used)
- Property injection
- Bastard injection

I'm not asking for an explanation for patterns/methods, rather I would just like the terms so i can read up on them myself!

Comment: I don't think this question is a good fit for SO. I'd advice you read this book: https://manning.com/seemann/

Comment: @Steven Thank you! I'm slightly lost as to what to look for, I'll check it out!